# Is there any API reference documentation for OAuth2 and especially Keycloak?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, documentation, openid-connect

I'm currently implementing Keycloak in my application and encounter a problem - I can not find any documentation except of keycloak.org Guides, which are not enough for me.

I've also tried searching through OpenID Connect specifications, nothing there.

What I want is a single resource with clear and handy docs for each HTTP endpoint of Keycloak (not for Keycloak-Admin), e. g. for `/login` endpoint and all possible use cases of that endpoint. So I can understand, how to use all these endpoints.

Where can I found this? I've spent several hours only googling for tiny bits of information and this seems unacceptable for me.

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak is an OpenID connect implementations, OIDC in its turn is a spec built on top of OAuth2 framework, so i suggest you to read following resources (in specified order):

[OAuth2 Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749)

[OIDC Core Spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) (Note sections like "[Authorization | Token | UserInfo] endpoint")

[Keycloak OIDC docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#endpoints)

I would also suggest you to read other OIDC Specs from https://openid.net/connect/ to get full picture

Also note that for example `/login` is not an endpoint from OIDC spec, its just a detail of Keycloak implementation.